# how do i tar a directory of files and folder without including one folder

Tags: unix

how do i tar a directory of files and folder without including one folder

Comment: Using what? bash script, a file manager, some other programming/scripting language? Tell us more.

Answer (score 2):

In a UNIX shell, you would use:

```
tar --exclude {dir-name} {dir-to-tar} > {tar-file}
```

where {dir-name} is the directory (or file) to exclude.

Comment: afaik I know --exclude is exclusive to gnu tar.